# How to maximize the fraction of the square of the sum of some sine and cosine functions

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, maxima-minima

I have a problem with maximizing the fraction of the square of the sum of some sine and cosine functions. Denote $\mathbf{x} \triangleq {(x_i)}_{i \in \{1,2,...,N\}}$. The problem is shown below. 
$$\max_{\mathbf{x}} \frac{A({(\sum_{i = 1}^N \cos(x_i - a_i))}^2+{(\sum_{i = 1}^N \sin(x_i - a_i))}^2)}{B({(\sum_{i = 1}^N \cos(x_i - b_i))}^2+ {(\sum_{i = 1}^N \sin(x_i - b_i))}^2)+1}$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constant, and $\mathbf{a} \triangleq {(a_i)}_{i \in \{1,2,...,N\}}$ and $ \mathbf{b} \triangleq {(b_i)}_{i \in \{1,2,...,N\}}$ are known.

I tried some variable substitution and found it hard to handle sine and cosine functions decently.

Could anyone give me some hints to handle optimization problem with sine and cosine functions? Thanks!

Comment: I would try using Euler's formula and see if there is an other way of expressing it, and simplifying some of the terms.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Do you mean to express sine and cosine functions by $e^{j\theta}$? Actually, the square of the sum of the sine and cosine functions comes from the square of the modulus of a complex number ( and I still don't know how to handle it...)

Comment: Yes that was what I was suggesting. I think a lot of terms can be factorized if you do so and then it may be easier. But if this is where you come from then you probably already explored that direction.